# Exporting to a .SQL file without the Create Database included

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to generate a .sql file from my database that doesn't include the CREATE DATABASE code?

Regards
T.

Comment: Programatically or just via SSMS?

Comment: SSMS using generate script option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you launch the generate scripts wizard and on the first step where it asks do you want to script the entire database or specific objects, select the specific objects option, then tick all the boxes to select all the objects.

The resulting script will include all the database objects within the DB, but not the database itself.